# Objective C - Iphone app development. If main thread hung, how can we terminate the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My Main objective is, if dispatch_get_main_queue() - hung & not responds, terminate the app.

I have this piece of code,

```
dispatchSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0,
                                                          dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0));

double interval = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
uint64_t intervalTime = (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_timer(dispatchSource, startTime + intervalTime, intervalTime, 0);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(dispatchSource, ^{
    NSLog(@"Main Thread not reponding for 10 secs. Capture App terminated");
    exit(0);
});
NSLog(@"LOW");
dispatch_resume(dispatchSource);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    dispatch_source_cancel(dispatchSource);
```

This was working fine XCode simulator but not working in Real Devices as expected.

Why this piece of code is not working in real device?

We use UIWebView to load a page. The page has some flash video. When trying to load it, App gets hung. That particular webpage is not belongs us. Yes agreed, ideal way to avoid its get stuck. But we want a solution or a hack to come out of this problem

If there is anyother way to identify dispatch_get_main_queue() takes time - and closing it, that would be more helpful.

Comment: Why are you doing that?  That's not the way Apple want you to do things.  They would rather you left it alone and made every effort to ensure that the main thread doesn't get stuck.  Also why would it get stuck?

Comment: You can call `exit(0)` but that's clearly NOT recommended. It's synonym of a crash for the user.

Comment: @trojanfoe We use webview to load a page. The page has some flash video. When trying to load it, App gets hung. That particular webpage is not belongs us. Yes agreed, ideal way to avoid its get stuck. But we want a solution or a hack to come out of this problem

Comment: @Larme We using exit(0). But we need to execute only when dispatch_get_main_queue() not responds.

Comment: @NaveenKumar are you using WKWebView or UIWebView. WKWebView renders pages out of app process, so Main Thread shouldn't get stuck

Comment: @Roman We using UIWebView., because we need app to run on OS less than 8.

Comment: If the main thread hangs iOS will terminate your app for you... because it has crashed. Don't do this. Don't rely on this. Don't hang the main thread. Ever.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes true. Its not the right way. But we need a solution for this. App is not closing by itself, its keep on going.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I'd suggest you to try and inject some Javascript code into UIWebView to build something like Watchdog timer and just stop loading the page if it doesn't respond for let's say 1 minute or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to do. But if you know you are doing wrong, and still want to do it wrong, use like below.

1. Have a function like this,

   ```
   - (void)terminateApp:(NSTimer*)timer
   {
      if(mainQueueDispatchSuccessful)
      {
          [timer invalidate];
          timer = nil;
      }
      else
      {
          NSString *reasonString = @"Main thread not responding at SBLAppDelegate for 10 secs. Force Closing app.";
          NSLog(@"%@",reasonString);
          exit(0);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Use it before and after main queue dispatch like this.

   ```
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(terminateApp:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
           [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
           [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
       });

       mainQueueDispatchSuccessful = false;

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           mainQueueDispatchSuccessful = true;
           .......
           .......
           }
   ```

Thanks for all, for helping me.